# Считывание zip-файла с неизвестным xlsx в DataFrame Pandas напрямую из интернета

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, zip

У меня задача прямой обработки zip-файла из интернета, в котором лежит xlsx файл с постоянно-изменяемым именем.

У меня получилось скачать файл на диск, распаковать его через ZipFile и считать его в df по маске *.xlsx

Но интерес вызывает сделать DataFrame без сохранения файла на диск. 
Я нашел ответ уважаемого [MaxU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49157077/pandas-how-to-read-excel-file-from-zip-archive)  , но так и не понял как сюда включить URL и маску файла (*.xlsx)

Прошу помочь. Я не понимаю.
Вот [ссылка](https://www.iek.ru/products/price/price-IEK.zip) на пример файла, который я хочу напрямую считать в DF.

Покажите пример работы на основе приведенного файла по ссылке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общих чертах я бы сделал так:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import io
import zipfile


url = 'https://www.iek.ru/products/price/price-IEK.zip'

response = requests.get(url)

zipped = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response.content))
zfile = zipped.open(zipped.infolist()[0]) #0 - это индекс имени дескриптора первого
#файла в списке. Не забывайте об этом, особенно, если у вас в архиве несколько файлов.
df=pd.read_excel(zfile)
```

и тогда:

```
print(df)


                                      Дата актуальности:  \
0                                    2019-06-07 00:00:00   
1                                    Контактный телефон:   
2                                     +7 (495) 542 22 22   
3                                            info@iek.ru   
4                                                    NaN   
5                                                Артикул   
6                                                    NaN   
7                             01. Модульное оборудование        
...
# и т.д.
```